# C++: Function call precedence rules for calling functions on objects of derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading, multiple-inheritance

I have a `class Iterator`, for which I have defined various operator overloads for equality testing (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==` and `!=`) as friend functions. Prototype example:

```
friend bool operator<(const Iterator &A, const Iterator &B);
```

`class RevIterator` inherits (virtually) from `Iterator`. Naturally, I have had to overload the operators `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` for this class (as friend functions again). Prototype example:

```
friend bool operator<(const RevIterator &A, const RevIterator &B);
```

I also have a `class ConstIterator` which inherits (virtually) from `Iterator`, for which I have not defined more operator overloads (they are meant to behave in the same way as for `Iterator`).

Finally, I have a `class ConstRevIterator` which inherits from `RevIterator` and `ConstIterator`, for which I have not defined any operator overloads.

Visual class hierarchy:

```
class Iterator {};
class RevIterator : virtual public Iterator {};
class ConstIterator : virtual public Iterator {};
class ConstRevIterator : public RevIterator, public ConstIterator {};
```

My assumption was that for the operator `<`, for example, operating on two `ConstRevIterator`s, the function available for one of the parent classes, `RevIterator` (2nd func. prototype above) would be called, instead of the function for the grandparent class, `Iterator` (1st func. prototype above).

In summary, what are the rules for which function gets called on a reference to a 'grandchild' object, when there are functions available for its parent and grandparent classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption seems correct. You may find rules of overload resolution here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Here is the part concerning your question:

> 4. If Mid is derived (directly or indirectly) from Base, and Derived is derived (directly or indirectly) from Mid

> a) Derived* to Mid* is better than Derived* to Base*

> b) Derived to Mid& or Mid&& is better than Derived to Base& or Base&&

> c) Base::* to Mid::* is better than Base::* to Derived::*

> d) Derived to Mid is better than Derived to Base

> e) Mid* to Base* is better than Derived* to Base*

> f) Mid to Base& or Base&& is better than Derived to Base& or Base&&

> g) Mid::* to Derived::* is better than Base::* to Derived::*

> h) Mid to Base is better than Derived to Base

I also produced some code to verify it:
https://godbolt.org/z/bc47dzxvY

Comment: This is wonderful: just what I was looking for. Indeed, I have just done some tinkering around in my code and have observed this same behaviour, but it is very reassuring to see it on paper. +1 and accepted, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> In summary, what are the rules for which function gets called on a reference to a 'grandchild' object, when there are functions available for its parent and grandparent classes?

The answer here depends on what you mean by a "reference to a 'grandchild' object".

These will be statically bound, so if you have something like:

```cpp
void foo(Iterator &a, Iterator &b) {
    if (a != b) // ...
}
```

...it'll use `bool operator!=(const Iterator &, const Iterator &)` to do the comparison, even if the iterator you pass is a `ConstIterator`, `RevIterator` or `ConstRevIterator`.

On the other hand, if you have a function something like:

```cpp
void bar(ConstRevIterator &a, ConstRevIterator &b) { 
    if (a != b) // ...
}
```

Now, since you've directly specified that it's a reference to a `ConstRevItertor`, it'll use `bool operator!=(const ConstRevIterator &, const ConstRevIterator &)` to do the comparison.

If you want virtual behavior, so the behavior depends on the actual type passed rather than the type declared for the parameter, you'll typically something more like this:

```cpp
class Iterator {
protected:
    virtual bool isEq(Iterator const &other) const { 
      // implement test for equality
    }

    virtual bool isNeq(Iterator const &other) {
        return !(isEq(other));
    }

    // and so on for the other comparisons

    friend bool operator==(Iterator const &a, Iterator const &b) { 
        return a.operator==(b);
    }

    // and likewise for the other comparisons

};

class ConstIterator : public Iterator {
protected:
     bool isEq(ConstIterator const &other) const override {
         // ...
     }

     bool isNeq(ConstIterator const &other) const override {
         // ..
     }
     // and so on
};
```

In this case, you define virtual member functions to do the real comparisons, friend functions that take references to the base class, and invoke the virtual member functions do to the real comparison, so you'll get virtual dispatch, and the comparison will be done for the most derived type.

This has a bit of a problem though: all the functions get virtual dispatch, which can be on the slow side, especially for something as simple as comparing two iterators--virtual dispatch could easily take longer than the comparison itself.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer. If I had to do it over again, I would have done something along the lines of what you suggest (making the actual comparison functions virtual and inside of the class, instead of friend functions outside the class). At the moment though, I have been able to confirm that, indeed, `friend bool operator<(const RevIterator &A, const RevIterator &B)` is being called for the comparison between two `ConstRevIterator`s (since `RevIterator` (parent) is closer to `ConstRevIterator` than `Iterator` (grandparent) is. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl: As long as the iterator's static type and dynamic type match each other, and the types of the two iterators match each other, you should be all right. But you do lose type safety. For example: `ConstRevIterator a; Iterator b; if (a != b) /* ... */` will compile--but it'll try to use `bool operator!=(const Iterator &a, const Iterator &b)` to do the comparison. One way to prevent this would be to use private inheritance rather than public.

Comment: oh wow, that's an important point. I should have considered that. How would private inheritance prevent it?

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl: Private inheritance prevents implicit conversion from `derived *` /`derived &` to `base *`/`base &`.